# Yeoman with grunt-connect-proxy returns a ECONNREFUSED error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm trying to add [grunt-connect-proxy](https://github.com/drewzboto/grunt-connect-proxy) to a project that uses the latest yeoman + angular generator.

But, when hitting the road that should be forwarded (e.g. 127.0.0.1:9000/api/v1), the server returns this error:

```
An error has occurred: {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect"}
```

I used a modified Gruntfile: [same as here](https://gist.github.com/rocky-jaiswal/7134473) as recommended.

How I'm a supposed to debug this? Has anyone had a similar issue lately with grunt-connect-proxy?

I'm also interested in similar solutions for proxing api calls for an angular webapp, if you have any that actually work.

Thank you for helping me out! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally got it to work somehow.
But frankly, I don't get it. It was definitely related to `localhost` not being the same as `127.0.0.1`. How did it ended that way, I don't have a clue...

I'll share what I learned while doing this, as I found no real answer for debugging this staff out there on the web. Here is what I learned:

- grunt has a `--verbose` option that may help you see what's going on

If grunt-connect-proxy is configured correctly you must see something like this at startup:

```
Running "configureProxies" task
Proxy created for: /api/v1 to localhost:8000
```

In my case, the grunt server was running on `127.0.0.1:9000`, the second server on `localhost:8000`. I proxied requests made on `api/v1` so `grunt server --verbose` would output something like this on every proxied request:

```
Proxied request: /api/v1/test -> http://localhost:8000/api/v1/test
{
    "host": "127.0.0.1:9000",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "accept": "...",
    "user-agent": "...",
    "accept-encoding": "...",
    "accept-language": "...",
    "cookie": "..."
}
```

- the whole point of using a proxy is to avoid any unnecessary CORS configuration on your second server

This is because once deployed your frontend and backend code will coexist on the same server (= the grunt server is only needed at dev time). I wanted to stress that point, because @Ulugbek answer may suggest that you need CORS to make grunt-connect-proxy work.

- the ECONNREFUSED error happens when your second server is not responding

In my case, I discovered that `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test` was not responding even if `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/test` was. So, I messed around with the /etc/hosts a bit and solved the problem by making sure both endpoints were responding accordingly.

The same error may happen to you if the second server is not listening to the proxied endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Gruntfile is fine, the error is caused by your backend, i.e. localhost:3000 (probably Rails).

If it is Rails, it's a CORS problem. You need to allow rails to accept connection from grunt server. Add 'rack-cors' to your gemfile and configure it like this in your development.rb config file:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:9000'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :delete]
  end
end
```

Check this link for detailed setup, it helped me to get it working.

[Working with Angular.js and Rails](http://rockyj.in/2013/10/24/angular_rails.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually use Laravel 4 in the backend, but that shouldn't matter. I know how to solve the CORS problem with Laravel. I thought that the point of using grunt-connect-proxy was exactly to NOT add specific CORS setup on the backend, so your dev an production code acts the same way in that regard.

Comment: Yea, I thought so too, but couldn't get it to work with Rails until I explicitly allowed access from grunt (got the same error). Maybe that's the problem here too.
For me it helped that Rails server had a full debugging tool in command line. Can you see if the request actually reaches your back-end ?

Comment: The request never reaches the backend apparently. I used Fiddler to trace it back and I also manually logged any request that reaches my backend. It seems that the grunt connect server throws a 500, with the message I mentioned above, and no request ever reaches my backend according to the logs.
Besides, I also added CORS on the backend. When I make the request to localhost:3000 directly, everything works fine. It stops working when I do the same on localhost:9000 (which should be forwarded according to my proxy config).

Comment: Did you [rename CORS cookie & header used by Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#description_security-considerations) to match those used by Rails ?  Probably isn't the case since wrong cookie&header names should yield 403 status code.

Comment: No, I didn't have to rename cookie & header and yes, you would've gotten a different error then. Did you check grunt server log ? Maybe it has a more detailed description of what went wrong.

Comment: Running `rails server --binding=0.0.0.0` as well as the CORS configuration resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue while trying to develop locally using AngularJS with a Laravel backend.

I was able to get the grunt-conenct-proxy example working using the before mentioned Rails example: [Working with Angular.js and Rails](http://rockyj.in/2013/10/24/angular_rails.html), however when trying to connect locally to my laravel backend I would always get the ECONNREFUSED error.

The only real difference I could see was that the rails server was spinning up on 0.0.0.0. where as my apache server was running on localhost/127.0.0.1.  After changing my config for my apache sever to run at 0.0.0.0 using:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I was the able to connect to my backed without issue.  If anyone could comment and explain how/why this works I would be very grateful.

Comment: I had JS running via Node testing PHP running via Artisan on Travis (long story). This solved the issue for me too.

Comment: With a rails backend, I was able to resolve this using 0.0.0.0 as well.  I'm not a unix network expert so I don't know why it works - but for a local Rails server you need to pass the `--binding=` flag to `rails server`.

`rails server --binding=0.0.0.0`

The above worked for me!  No more ECONNREFUSED errors.